Dynamic columns to summarize in Power BI
Below is the sample data i have:

I have two date parameters which the user will select dynamically. Let say they select 2024-07-01 and 2024-10-30. i would need the values summarized for the months selected July-Oct in this case

and eventually summarized


why not use one date filter and let user to select the date range. Then i think we will get the output automatically.

First off, unpivot that, so you end up with (EmployeeCode, MonthYear, Amount). then this is just stupid easy. Just create a SUM() or AVERAGE() or whatever measure and use that in the Values.
